# Spark: A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

When trying to build MLlib example with Spark 1.2.1 using SBT I get the whole bunch of strange compilation errors. The same code builds fine with Spark 1.1.0. For Spark 1.2.1 I use the following SBT build file:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "1.2.1" % "provided"
```

As a result I get the following set of strange errors:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/test/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly
[error] in package scala.annotation which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
[error] /home/test/src/main/scala/Test.scala:16: Reference to method augmentString in object Predef should not have survived past type checking,
[error] it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
[error] val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
[error] /home/test/src/main/scala/Test.scala:16: Reference to method augmentString in object Predef should not have survived past type checking,
[error] it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
[error] val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
[error]                                                               ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed 26.02.2015 17:47:29
```

How to fix this? It would be great if somebody could post a general SBT to build Spark 1.2.1 + MLlib code. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps here but I was getting a similar error. My problem was that I added spark-core and spark-mllib as maven dependencies. This caused issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the libraryDependencies line to the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.2.1" % "provided"
```

You are using Scala 2.10.4 and you are trying to install the Spark library for Scala 2.11.x - the %% will automatically select the correct Scala library version for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ to compile spark 1.6.0 code. And faced the same errors. [ERROR] error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly.

I solve this problem by adding Scala language related dependencies to the project. Maybe maven can't use the Scala config from Intellij. So we should explicitly specify the Scala dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.6</version>
</dependency>
```